# popup/dropdown for reputation display

Tags: feature-request, user-card

The popup that appears when you hover over your username...can it also display when hovering over the reputation link. Because the popup *mostly* contains reputation information (well it takes up the majority of the space). I naturally tend to hover over the reputation link and when nothing appears I remember to move to the username

Just a thought...

Comment: What is the motivation here: ease of use, encouraging users to gain more reputation? It seems like a simple thing to implement, but why do it?

Comment: @this.josh I find that I regularly move the mouse over the reputation count to see the reputation display as a natural tendency...and as the app doesn't do what I naturally think it should, others may well do the same...so it could be an improvement...its logical and there isn't another popup, so it's not competing...